# Regex find value between a space and period for Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have the following cell values:

```
LOT: 4 SP: 144731
LOT: 7 RP: 804923
LOT: 6 RP: 804923
```

I want to obtain:

```
SP
RP
RP
```

I have been trying the following where the values are in column N:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(N2,"LOT: [1-9]+? :"),TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(N2,".*?(?:LOT: ([1-9]+?) :|$)","$1 ")),))
```

Getting the lot value using the following worked but I need the SP/RP etc value

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(N2,"LOT: .+? RP:"),TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(N2,".*?(?:LOT: (.+?) RP:|$)","$1 ")),))
```

Comment: Try `=REGEXEXTRACT(N2, "LOT:\s+\S+\s+(\S+):")`

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Please put it in as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just did, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(N2, "LOT:\s+\S+\s+(\S+):")
```

**Details**

- `LOT:` - a literal substring `LOT:`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 (this part will be returned by the `REGEXEXTRACT` function): 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `:` - a colon

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7DfL9y/1).

Answer (score 1):

for text in `A1`:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d (.*):")`

ArrayFormula for text in `A1:A3`:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"\d (.*):"))`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could formulate a `REGEX` expression. The common base idea is to find the  "anchor"- the common factor.

There's already a strong accepted answer written by a expert. I'll just provide a couple of alternative solutions based on *some assumptions* based on the data provided by you:

#### Anchor `P`:

Assuming the extract will always contain a `P`. Provided everything else remains the same,the easiest and shortest one:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(N1,"\wP")
```

#### Anchor Space:

Assuming there's always a space before the required extract and it's the only space before the two non `D`igit:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(N1," (\D\D)")
```

#### Anchor `:`:

Two `w`ord characters followed by a `:`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(N1,"\b(\w\w):")
```